# What is a "delta-qualification" program?

Tags: failure, reliability

In the [NASA Independent Review of the Antares Orb-3 failure](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/orb3_irt_execsumm_0.pdf), they refer to a "delta-qualification program":

> As a result, this area of the turbopump is vulnerable to oxygen fire and failures. The AJ26 engines were not subjected to a thorough delta-qualification program to demonstrate their operational capability and margin for use on Antares. Performing a thorough delta-qualification program for Antares would likely have revealed these issues.

But I can't seem to find any information on what such a program would entail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to re-testing an already qualified design after making changes to it.

Per the USAF Space Command's [EVALUATION AND TEST REQUIREMENTS FOR LIQUID ROCKET ENGINES](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/1037878.pdf):

> Qualification testing should be performed on the final design, manufacturing processes, procedures, and acceptance program to be used for flight units.
>   [7.11.2-1] **Deviations following completion of [liquid rocket engine] qualification shall require that the system be re-qualified (i.e., “delta-qualification”)** via combination of evaluation and test (including the option
>   of not requiring delta-qualification), with concurrence of the Approval Authority, where deviations include configuration changes, modified processes, new suppliers, new facilities, or revised procedures.

i.e. "If you change something, you need to re-qualify it, but if the change is minor enough we can just agree that it's re-qualified."

I don't know exactly how it would apply in the case of the AJ-26/Antares situation.

Comment: Excellent answer. The space business if *full* of delta-X's where X can be "qualification", "PDR" (Preliminary Design Review, the big-deal review that gives a project authority to begin detailed design), "CDR" (Critical Design Review, the big-deal review that gives a project authority to start cutting/bending metal), etc. I've been on multiple such delta-review boards, where for instance a pre-project team miscalculated the ∆V a mission would need, thus underestimating the mass of propellant it would need, thus underestimating the tank mass, support structure, etc. Redesign and a delta-review!

Comment: @Tom I guess a delta-delta-V review would have been warranted :P

Comment: Ha!! Good one!!

Comment: Origin of the term: in physics, the "delta" symbol is used as the abbreviation of "the change of" (delta-V: the change in speed). Hence, change in configuration also became a delta.